# Max number of items per filter in layered navigation

Tags: layered-navigation, filter

I would like to have a maximum number of items, say 10, per filter in layered navigation with a More... link that would then load all of the items for that filter.
This would be really useful for the brands filter as there are a lot of them.

Any info/tutorials would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can suggest you [this](https://amasty.com/improved-layered-navigation.html) extension you can get everything you need for Layered navigation.

Answer (score 1):

The layered nav options are displayed using the template `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml`.
If you want you can add your logic in there.
But I don't recommend this approach. Doing it like this 10 of your brands (or other filter) will always get more visibility than the rest of them. I'm no SEO specialist but I think that having hidden links will affect your page rank (Can someone confirm or bust this?).

I suggest having a `max-height` on each filter type with an overflow scroll.

Comment: From a performance perspective I highly recommend using the more approach. Layered navigation should not be crawled to begin with: infinite combinations resulting in a heavy penalty for consuming a lot of the crawlers time and the results are subsets of content displayed elsewhere.

Comment: @Melvyn. Thanks for clearing the SEO thing. But I still think the 'more' approach is less user friendly. But this is just my opinion.

Comment: Depends how well you implement it. For logged in customers you can opt to allow them to configure a set of defaults. You can show the most popular brands first, or brands you want to promote. You can also do a delayed fetch using Ajax, to cut down on the initial load time and fetch the rest through one request. More is less applies to showing everything as well: too many choices can be cluttering.

Comment: @Melvyn My SEO is setup with rel="canonical" for category pages. Hopefully this stops crawlers crawling the filters. I have seen lots of ajax layered navigation extensions, maybe one of them has this functionality already. The popular brands first is a good idea. Looks like I should look up some ajax magento tutorials too.

Comment: It does eventually. But since the bot has to first request the filtered page to parse it's canonical it will take a while. But don't take my word for it, check your webserver logs and see what pages are requested by crawlers.

Comment: @Melvyn - You are totally right - So I found a tutorial that will add rel="nofollow" to filters links in layered nav [link](http://mage101.com/?p=272) - That should stop crawlers from wandering around aimlessly!